# Deploying NodeJS to godaddy

Tags: node.js, hosting, root, putty, godaddy-api

I have a domain on godaddy, and a **Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel**.
I wanted to host a NodeJS app.
Searching the web I learned I needed an **application manager** that I couldn't find In my **Software** section on cPanel.

I contacted support to learn that I need to upgrade in order to have the application manager and WHM access.

yet the support told me that I can still deploy without any of that but the support doesn't cover it.

I have putty access and i went through the trouble of installing nvm and having the **GLIBC_2.16'** errors.

How can I deploy a NodeJS app from a repository using `Putty` to my domain without paying the money to have root acces to my server.

**Update**

So I was able to install node using `nvm` using:

- `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`

I used this very useful article "https://www.codepunker.com/blog/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm-on-a-shared-cpanel-whm-hosting-account"

From there install any version of node using `nvm install vxxxxx`
but every time I login using ssh I get the `libgc2.16` error and I have to use `nvm use v10.0.0` for example to have node.

The problem now is since I have node working on my hosting server.
Is there a guide to how to access my node website from my domain?

**Update**

So, I got to running my app by uploading it to `/public_html`
and adding a `.htaccess` in the same directory with the following inside it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

then I had the problem of `Cannot GET /index.html.var`
which I solved by adding

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

to my `.htaccess file`

Now I'm stuck with my server crashing every 5 minutes were I have to login to my terminal
type : `nvm use v10.0.0` to be able to start my server or else I'll have the following:

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
```

How can I solve that?

**Update**

I solved this using `nvm alias default v10.0.0`

Now my server keeps crashing when ever I lose connection to my cPanel seccion.

How can I solve that?

**Update**

So installing forever seems to do the trick:

`npm install forever -g`
and in my `public_html` directory I did:
`forever start app.js`

Will close the question once I make sure the problem is solved.

Comment: backend only works like charm, but i'm struggling with integrating vue app with node backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has portable binaries that you can find here: [Latest version (Node 16.2)](https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.2.0/), [LTS (Node 14.17)](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.0/). They include the binaries for node, npm and npx.

Answer (score 0):

The above steps and details were enough to run my app even when I'm not logged in to my cPanel session, I hope this regroupment of multiple searches over the web would help everyone looking to deploy their NodeJS apps on the Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel.
on godaddy.